# MS Access Relationship Questions

Tags: python, database, ms-access, report

[image]I've got a .mdb that opens with the ability to select a value from a drop down (Setup Main window with Pragram Data field). This then generates the Setup Data window. This information is all pulled from relationships between different tables, yet when I view relationships there are no connections between the tables? The small buttons to the mid/upper right (Op sheet, Tool Sheet, etc) all generate a report to be printed. I also cannot find where these reports come from or the connections between them and the Setup Data window. Anyone familiar with MS Access can give some guidance into viewing these things?

My goal is to recreate these reports in a Python Pandas dataframe or similar. I've connected to the .mdb using pyodbc already and can load them into a df but am unsure how these connections are made?

Comment: You can try holding the [Shift] key down as you open the database in Access. That may bypass the startup code (if the developer hasn't disabled that feature) and allow you to open the form(s) in Design View. From there you can inspect the Events associated with the form controls to see what they do (e.g., a button Click event may call `DoCmd.OpenReport` to open a Report).

Comment: Thanks Gord, I was able to view the VB code to each from. Looks like its a mess, tons of blank or partially entered forms and tables. I wasn't sure of the keywords, 'Events' to use as a description. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try holding the [Shift] key down as you open the database in Access. That may bypass the startup code (if the developer hasn't disabled that feature) and allow you to open the Form(s) in Design View. From there you can inspect the Events associated with the Form controls to see what they do (e.g., a button Click event may call `DoCmd.OpenReport` to open a Report).

Specifically with regard to Relationships, the developer may have simply not bothered to define them in the Relationships window. However, you can still identify the relationships between the tables by looking at the JOINs in saved queries, including the queries defined as the Record Source of a Report.